# Passing values from different classes in python

Tags: python

I am new to the python programming. I met a problem now that I want to call some results from one class to another class as one of the  `__init__` attributes. Here is the code shown below: (reduced_data is numerical data in vector)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, k=3, tol=0.0001, max_iter=300):
        self.k = k
        self.tol = tol
        self.max_iter = max_iter

    def fit(self, data):

        self.centroids = {}

        for i in range(self.k):
            self.centroids[i] = data[i+50]

        for i in range(self.max_iter):
            self.classifications = {}

            for i in range(self.k):
                self.classifications[i] = []

            for featureset in data:
                distances = [np.linalg.norm(featureset - self.centroids[centroid]) for centroid in self.centroids]
                classification = distances.index(min(distances))
                self.classifications[classification].append(featureset)
            prev_centroids = dict(self.centroids)

            for classification in self.classifications:
                self.centroids[classification] = np.average(self.classifications[classification], axis=0)

            optimized = True

            for c in self.centroids:
                original_centroid = prev_centroids[c]
                current_centroid = self.centroids[c]
                if np.sum((current_centroid - original_centroid) / original_centroid * 100.0) > self.tol:
                    #print(np.sum((current_centroid - original_centroid) / original_centroid * 100.0))
                    optimized = False

            if optimized:
                break
            
    def cluster_labels(self,data):
        cluster_labels = []
        for featureset in data:
            distances=[np.linalg.norm(featureset - self.centroids[centroid]) for centroid in self.centroids]
            cluster_labels.append(distances.index(min(distances)))
        return cluster_labels

class B:
        x = np.linalg.norm(reduced_data-[1,1])
        k = (x-5)^2
        a = A()
        a.fit(reduced_data)
        y_pred = a.predict(reduced_data)
        labels = a.cluster_labels(reduced_data)
```

Basically, I want to pass the value k in class B as the attribute of class A in `def __init__(self, k=k in class B, tol=0.0001, max_iter=300):`And how could I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: change the third line in class B to: `a = A(k=k)`.

But ask yourself a more fundamental question.  Why is "class B" a class at all?  As you have written it, it doesn't have any "self" properties, so it has no preserved state.  You calculate y_pred and labels exactly once.  These are class attributes.
After that, they never change.  I suggest that you just eliminate the class and place the last six lines in the main body of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the parameters from the `__init__` method when creating a new instance of that object.

I.e. `a = A(k)`.

Note that in class `B`, the code is not inside a method. You may want to put that code outside of the class definition. In Python, code doesn't have to inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

Your **class** `A` doesn't have the attribute `k`, however it's **instance** does.

So you either should make `k` a class attribute of `A` or pass the value of instance of `A.k` to `B` each time.